# Creating new Child Windows from NSWindowController results in very small window

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

I have added a Setting button to my Toolbar in my app. Clicking on the setting button will generate a new Window with my apps' settings.

For Yosemite users - they are greeted with a tiny Window which they can't resize. 
eg: 
[image: Tiny window]
Here is the view in my storyboard: 
[image: Image from Storyboard]

and here is the code I use to show it.

```
  @IBAction func amenubtn_settings(sender: NSToolbarItem) {
    let storyboard = NSStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

  let numWindows = NSApplication.sharedApplication().windows


  let destinationController = storyboard.instantiateControllerWithIdentifier("Settings") as! SettingsVC

  let newWindow = NSWindow(contentViewController: destinationController)
    destinationController.delegate = self

    self.window?.addChildWindow(newWindow, ordered: .Above

    )
}
```

Can you help me by letting me know if there is a way to make sure that the window is the correct size to show the content, or else is there a way to launch the window directly from the main View Controller as a sheet/ popover?

Comment: check for errant constraints. delete anything that looks suspicious. check the window size in IB.

Comment: @johnelemans where do I see the Window Size?

Comment: see here.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55965290/set-nswindow-size-programmatically-doesnt-work